# Do we need to apply Sql Transaction in both C# code and Stored Procedure also?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which is updating multiple tables in SQL Server. This procedure is being used from C# code.

If I apply the transaction only in C# code would it be a good practice?

Do I need to apply transaction in both C# code and stored procedure?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the process is only calling a single stored procedure in a single `SqlCommand`, then just handle the transaction inside the stored procedure and there is no need to manage it from the C# code. You would only need to manage it in the C# code in order to maintain the transaction across multiple `SqlCommand` executions.

FYI, managing the transaction in both layers is only necessary if both of the following are true:

- the C# code is making multiple `SqlCommand` calls that need to be considered a single operation
- the stored procedure(s) can/will be called by outside of this C# code, such as by other stored procedures (in which case there might not be an existing Transaction at the time the stored procedure(s) is/are called.

Outside of the above scenario, managing the transaction in both layers is pointless as there is only a single transaction. If the transaction is started in the C# code, then all that happens in the stored procedure when `BEGIN TRAN` is called is that `@@TRANCOUNT` is incremented. And the transaction is not truly committed until the `@@TRANCOUNT` comes back down to 0 by issuing the same number of `COMMIT`s as shown in `@@TRANCOUNT` (in this case, issuing a `COMMIT` in the stored procedure and again in the C# code, at which point SQL Server actually does the real "commit"). However, a single `ROLLBACK` brings `@@TRANCOUNT` back to 0 no matter what number it was at. And if that happens in the Stored Proc, you cannot issue either a `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` in the C# code as the transaction no longer exists, so you would need to test for an active transaction first.

Assuming that you are using at least SQL Server 2005, if not newer, be sure to use the T-SQL `TRY / CATCH` syntax to manage the `COMMIT / ROLLBACK` within the stored procedure.  *You will need the TRY / CATCH syntax to properly catch errors and exit the proc(s) even if you are only managing the transaction in the C# code.*

For example:

```sql
BEGIN TRY

  BEGIN TRAN;

     UPDATE Table1 ... ;

     UPDATE Table2 ... ;

     UPDATE Table3 ... ;

  COMMIT TRAN;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

  IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
  BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRAN;
  END;

  THROW; -- if using SQL Server 2012 or newer, else use RAISERROR

END CATCH;
```

Comment: Oh deity, nested SQL Server transactions .. avoid like the plague. At least triggers aren't involved. This is one of the few areas where I would kick an SQL Server developer, given a chance.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I am executing multiple SqlCommand and each commands are updating multiple tables using proc in Sql Server 2008 R2, So in that case if I use Transaction only at C# code level, that would work fine?

Comment: @AbhishekSrivastava: check my updated answer as I addressed that scenario while you must have been adding the comment ;-). It all comes down to whether or not those Stored Procedures can be called by other Stored Procedures, or individually by other C# code that might not be wrapped in a transaction.

Comment: @AbhishekSrivastava: You will still need the TRY / CATCH syntax to properly catch errors and exit the proc.